Start docker service fails unregulary azure pipeline
The step to start docker service fails unregulary on azure. Any ideas what could help?
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: 'Start docker deamon'
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo Start docker deamon
        wsl -- bash -c "sudo service docker start"


What exactly do you mean by fails unregulary on azure? Could you please edit your post and provide us more details? Is there any error message? Are you using self-hosted build agents? ...

To start the docker daemon, you can use operating system utilities. Run sudo systemctl start docker to start the daemon and run sudo systemctl status docker to check the status of the Docker service. See more info from Start the daemon.
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      sudo systemctl start docker
      sudo systemctl status docker

Then I can see the status of the docker is active (running).

